# How to get user id from a logged user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication

How can I get an Id from a logged user? I need this Id to make a insert in the database. I am thinking in save it in a session, and then using it in another controller. Here's my login controller.

```
public ActionResult Login(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (new AllFictionMembershipProvider().ValidateUser(login.Email, Criptografia.Encriptar(login.Senha)))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Email, false);


                return RedirectToDefault();

            }
        }

        return View(login);
    }
```

I want to create a session and save the id of this user after user's login. How can I do it? Can someone explain? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the email address that was successfully validated, and query it against the user's table to find the ID.

Comment: Can you show how I can do it? I'm in trouble here, because I need to use this ID in another controller...

Comment: What is your data source?  SQL Server, MySQL, or what?

Comment: I am using sql server.

Comment: Then you need to execute a stored procedure or SQL query, using ADO.NET to communicate to SQL via the raw API, or use an ORM like Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Does  ID is a primary key in the database? If it is,you can use a function to get the id.
alse the Login struct can hold a ID field. Then can do this:login.Id = id.

```
public long GetId()
{
  //.....get the id 
  return id;
}
```